# What's the best way to declare a non-rust repository as a dependency in a rust project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a rust project where I want to use protobuf definitions that exist in another, non-rust repository.

I'm planning to download the protobuf repository, create a `src/common_protobuf` module in my main repository, use `cargo build` to generate all the rust implementations of each protobuf into the `common_protobuf` module, then selectively re-export the generated structures into their intended modules with `pub use`.

I can't seem to find the best way to specify the dependency. Using

```
[build-dependencies]
pbrepo = { git="https://github.com/username/pbrepo" }
```

results in

```
Caused by:
  Could not find Cargo.toml in `/Users/username/.cargo/git/checkouts/pbrepo-33abcde7dddd6356/fdefgd9`
```

I can't commit a `Cargo.toml` into the external repository. I considered using a git submodule or making a [sys-crate](https://kornel.ski/rust-sys-crate) with the submodule and Cargo.toml but I prefer to have my build dependencies in a single place and not have to synchronize multiple repos during a build.

I could download the repository manually in the the build scripts and set the commit to pull in my `build.rs` but again I would like to have all my build dependencies in one place.

Is there a mechanism to accomplish this or is this a better way to use remote protobuf definitions?

Comment: You can link to them, as a git submodule/subtree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cargo does not support downloading non-Rust dependencies. The only things that you can have Cargo download for you are Cargo packages (loosely “crates”).

Even if you added a `Cargo.toml` to your non-Rust repository, that would not help, since there is no way to ask for the location of that dependency to read from it. Cargo's dependencies mechanism lets you depend on a *built library* only, not its source files (as far as I know; I could have missed something).

You will have to use some separate procedure that downloads the dependency (custom script, git submodule…) before running `cargo build`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [cargo-make](https://github.com/sagiegurari/cargo-make#usage-task-dependencies-alias)

It allows for more complex dependency tracking and building things from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69965299) use Cargo directly, you have to resort to a higher-level mechanism, such as Git submodules, which can be [downloaded automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71726734) before building via `build.rs`. This way `cargo build` will both fetch the submodule and build your project in a single command.